# ToggleSlide 2 instances of same class - Slide works but only 1 hides

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have 2 instances of the same class (.attributes) in my html. I simply want them both to toggle at the same time. The first instance works as expected, but the 2nd instance continues to Toggle open (style remains display:block).

Relevant HTML in both locations

```
<div class="attributes">
content to hide
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.attributes').hide();
    $('a#toggle-attributes').click(function() {
        $('.attributes').slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've taken the "working" class out of the picture by giving it a different name but I get the same results. There is an unordered list along with a div in the class that won't toggle to hidden.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you returning false and killing the passage of the jquery object?

Comment: @Babiker: Returning false from an event handler cancels the default behavior of the event, and if the `event` parameter of the callback is not being used, it may be ommitted.

Comment: I think your JS is fine, check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/h6xc4/.  What's different in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I tried following on my local.

```
    <a id="toggle-attributes" href="#">toggle</a>
<div class="attributes">
    content to hide
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br /><br />
<div class="attributes">
    content to hide
</div>
```

It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so this is set up correctly. What should I look for that could be stopping the 2nd instance from hiding? As I said, it will pull the .hide() originally, and will do the toggleslide effect, but it never re-hides. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

More info:  This code is being used in a new Pinnacle cart store. I'm hiding the attributes (form with many selects) area on a product page (this is toggling as expected) and also hiding additional images in a different column. I'll change the format of what is wrapped (simple text vs what is currently there) and report back if this works and my findings. Should have thought of this previously, but am still pretty new to jQuery.

Thanks.